Advancing to the next video using PyQt6
I am trying to run a PyQt6 example , but the method to advance the video player to the next clip gets the UI stuck (unresponsive). How can I fix that?
The code to move to the next clip is
@Slot()
def next_clicked(self):
    print(f"next_from {self._playlist_index}")
    self._playlist_index = (self._playlist_index + 1) % len(self._playlist)
    self._player.setSource(self._playlist[self._playlist_index])

I have checked that I have a valid playlist containing more than one clip, and the index correctly progresses from n-1 to 0, etc. Once setSource() is executed, the UI becomes unresponsive and needs to be killed.
I am running this on Windows 11 with the latest patches and Python 3.11.
UPDATE: The code works better with shorter clips (~20s) and on a faster drive (C: vs external USB), so the problems might be due to synchronization, i.e., I should not attempt to play a clip before it is fully loaded. But how can I do that, i.e., which event do I need to handle? (Hypothetically:   onMediaLoaded() self._player.play()).
The code posted below is a complete example. It should run for you as is, and allow you to open a clip from a directory containing several clips in MP4 format. When you press the "Next clip" button, it may become unresponsive.
Running with QT_FFMPEG_DEBUG=1 does not print any debug messages.
My code, which is virtually identical to the example:
# see https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/examples/example_multimedia_player.html

"""PySide6 Multimedia player example"""

import sys
import os
import glob
from PySide6.QtCore import QStandardPaths, Qt, Slot, QUrl
from PySide6.QtGui import QAction, QIcon, QKeySequence
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog, QFileDialog,
                               QMainWindow, QSlider, QStyle, QToolBar)
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import (QAudioOutput, QMediaFormat,
                                  QMediaPlayer)
from PySide6.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget

AVI = "video/x-msvideo"  # AVI

MP4 = 'video/mp4'


def get_supported_mime_types():
    result = []
    for f in QMediaFormat().supportedFileFormats(QMediaFormat.Decode):
        mime_type = QMediaFormat(f).mimeType()
        result.append(mime_type.name())
    return result


def is_directory(path):
    return os.path.isdir(path)


def list_files_with_extension(directory, extension):
    if not extension.startswith('.'):
        extension = '.' + extension
    search_path = os.path.join(directory, '*' + extension)
    return glob.glob(search_path)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._playlist = []  # FIXME 6.3: Replace by QMediaPlaylist?
        self._playlist_index = -1
        self._audio_output = QAudioOutput()
        self._player = QMediaPlayer()
        self._player.setAudioOutput(self._audio_output)

        self._player.errorOccurred.connect(self._player_error)

        tool_bar = QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(tool_bar)

        file_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&File")
        icon = QIcon.fromTheme(QIcon.ThemeIcon.DocumentOpen)
        open_action = QAction(icon, "&Open...", self,
                              shortcut=QKeySequence.Open, triggered=self.open)
        file_menu.addAction(open_action)
        tool_bar.addAction(open_action)
        icon = QIcon.fromTheme(QIcon.ThemeIcon.ApplicationExit)
        exit_action = QAction(icon, "E&xit", self,
                              shortcut="Ctrl+Q", triggered=self.close)
        file_menu.addAction(exit_action)

        play_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&Play")
        style = self.style()
        icon = QIcon.fromTheme(QIcon.ThemeIcon.MediaPlaybackStart,
                               style.standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
        self._play_action = tool_bar.addAction(icon, "Play")
        self._play_action.triggered.connect(self._player.play)
        play_menu.addAction(self._play_action)

        icon = QIcon.fromTheme(QIcon.ThemeIcon.MediaSkipBackward,
                               style.standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaSkipBackward))
        self._previous_action = tool_bar.addAction(icon, "Previous")
        self._previous_action.triggered.connect(self.previous_clicked)
        play_menu.addAction(self._previous_action)

        icon = QIcon.fromTheme(QIcon.ThemeIcon.MediaPlaybackPause,
                               style.standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPause))
        self._pause_action = tool_bar.addAction(icon, "Pause")
        self._pause_action.triggered.connect(self._player.pause)
        play_menu.addAction(self._pause_action)

        icon = QIcon.fromTheme(QIcon.ThemeIcon.MediaSkipForward,
                               style.standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaSkipForward))
        self._next_action = tool_bar.addAction(icon, "Next")
        self._next_action.triggered.connect(self.next_clicked)
        play_menu.addAction(self._next_action)

        icon = QIcon.fromTheme(QIcon.ThemeIcon.MediaPlaybackStop,
                               style.standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaStop))
        self._stop_action = tool_bar.addAction(icon, "Stop")
        self._stop_action.triggered.connect(self._ensure_stopped)
        play_menu.addAction(self._stop_action)

        #{ Add a Delete button
        icon = QIcon.fromTheme(QIcon.ThemeIcon.MediaRecord,
                               style.standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaVolumeMuted))
        self._delete_action = tool_bar.addAction(icon, "Delete")
        self._delete_action.triggered.connect(self._delete_media)
        play_menu.addAction(self._delete_action)
        #} Add a Delete button

        self._volume_slider = QSlider()
        self._volume_slider.setOrientation(Qt.Horizontal)
        self._volume_slider.setMinimum(0)
        self._volume_slider.setMaximum(100)
        available_width = self.screen().availableGeometry().width()
        self._volume_slider.setFixedWidth(available_width / 10)
        self._volume_slider.setValue(self._audio_output.volume())
        self._volume_slider.setTickInterval(10)
        self._volume_slider.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksBelow)
        self._volume_slider.setToolTip("Volume")
        self._volume_slider.valueChanged.connect(self._audio_output.setVolume)
        tool_bar.addWidget(self._volume_slider)

        icon = QIcon.fromTheme(QIcon.ThemeIcon.HelpAbout)
        about_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&About")
        about_qt_act = QAction(icon, "About &Qt", self, triggered=qApp.aboutQt)  # noqa: F821
        about_menu.addAction(about_qt_act)

        self._video_widget = QVideoWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._video_widget)
        self._player.playbackStateChanged.connect(self.update_buttons)
        self._player.setVideoOutput(self._video_widget)

        self.update_buttons(self._player.playbackState())
        self._mime_types = []

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self._ensure_stopped()
        event.accept()

    @Slot()
    def open(self):
        self._ensure_stopped()
        file_dialog = QFileDialog(self)

        is_windows = sys.platform == 'win32'
        if not self._mime_types:
            self._mime_types = get_supported_mime_types()
            if (is_windows and AVI not in self._mime_types):
                self._mime_types.append(AVI)
            elif MP4 not in self._mime_types:
                self._mime_types.append(MP4)

        file_dialog.setMimeTypeFilters(self._mime_types)

        #efault_mimetype = AVI if is_windows else MP4
        default_mimetype = MP4
        if default_mimetype in self._mime_types:
            file_dialog.selectMimeTypeFilter(default_mimetype)

        movies_location = QStandardPaths.writableLocation(QStandardPaths.MoviesLocation)
        file_dialog.setDirectory(movies_location)
        if file_dialog.exec() == QDialog.Accepted:
            url = file_dialog.selectedUrls()[0]
            print(f"Opening {url.toString()}")
            if url.isLocalFile():
                file_url = url.toLocalFile()
                if is_directory(file_url):
                    self.append_files(file_url)
                else:
                    dir_url = os.path.dirname(file_url)
                    self.append_files(dir_url)
            self._player.play()

    def append_file(self, url):
        self._playlist.append(url)
        self._playlist_index = len(self._playlist) - 1
        self._player.setSource(url)


    def append_files(self, dir_url):
        files = list_files_with_extension(dir_url, 'mp4')
        urls = [QUrl.fromLocalFile(file) for file in files]
        for url in urls:
            self.append_file(url)

    @Slot()
    def _ensure_stopped(self):
        if self._player.playbackState() != QMediaPlayer.StoppedState:
            self._player.stop()

    @Slot()
    def _delete_media(self):
        playing_now = self._playlist[self._playlist_index]
        print(f"Delete {playing_now}")

    @Slot()
    def previous_clicked(self):
        # Go to previous track if we are within the first 5 seconds of playback
        # Otherwise, seek to the beginning.
        if self._player.position() <= 5000 and self._playlist_index > 0:
            self._playlist_index -= 1
            self._playlist.previous()
            self._player.setSource(self._playlist[self._playlist_index])
        else:
            self._player.setPosition(0)

    @Slot()
    def next_clicked(self):
        print(f"next_from {self._playlist_index}")
        self._playlist_index = (self._playlist_index + 1) % len(self._playlist)
        self._player.setSource(self._playlist[self._playlist_index])
        #self._player.play()


    @Slot("QMediaPlayer::PlaybackState")
    def update_buttons(self, state):
        media_count = len(self._playlist)
        self._play_action.setEnabled(media_count > 0 and state != QMediaPlayer.PlayingState)
        self._pause_action.setEnabled(state == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState)
        self._stop_action.setEnabled(state != QMediaPlayer.StoppedState)
        self._previous_action.setEnabled(self._player.position() > 0)
        self._next_action.setEnabled(media_count > 1)

    def show_status_message(self, message):
        self.statusBar().showMessage(message, 5000)

    @Slot("QMediaPlayer::Error", str)
    def _player_error(self, error, error_string):
        print(error_string, file=sys.stderr)
        self.show_status_message(error_string)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_win = MainWindow()
    available_geometry = main_win.screen().availableGeometry()
    main_win.resize(available_geometry.width() / 3,
                    available_geometry.height() / 2)
    main_win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


Can you please provide a comprehensive [mre]? Also, what Qt (not PyQt) version?

@musicamante The code I am trying to run is the one in the link, with insignificant changes. I am using PyQt6 and this is my first contact with it, so I don't know what version of Qt it is using under the hood. I have installed PySide6 and tried to run the example.


questions should always be self-contained, as the contents of the link may be changed over time (therefore making the question invalid); 2. we cannot base our replies on your assumption about "insignificant changes" (you also are new to Qt, so you may not realize that a change that looks irrelevant to you could actually be quite important); 3. the post is tagged/titled for PyQt, but now you say that you're using PySide; they're not the same; clarify which one you actually use and do a basic search on getting the actual Qt version. Please do provide a proper [mre].


That said, external drives are notoriously slow: does the problem also happen if the first media in the list is loaded from there? It's unknown what type of USB drive you're using, if it's a magnetic drive, it may require some time to start spinning the disks and finally retrieve the data (especially if it's a large file, the disk is relatively full and its data is also fragmented). How much time did you actually wait since the freezing started? If the file eventually loads, does the problem also represents after trying to open it again? Beyond which size does the problem actually show up?

Post a [mre] with sample data and debugging details including Python environments. For example, what backend are you using? If you are using FFmpeg, did you try the environment variable QT_FFMPEG_DEBUG=1?
